# findTheOldest - Understanding reduce() method

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to figure out how the `reduce()` method is working on this script. Everything I read about the `reduce()` method goes over every area of the array and adds it together. This is from the Mozilla documentation.

```
let sum = [0, 1, 2, 3].reduce(function (accumulator, currentValue) {
  return accumulator + currentValue
}, 0)
// sum is 6
```

So how does this script compare all three objects in `people` and return the one that is the oldest? I am not following how this code is running. I do understand the `getAge` function is being run on `yearOfDeath - yearOfBirth` over every element in the object `people`. I do not understand how it is returning the one that is the oldest.

````
 const findTheOldest = function() {

            const people = [{
                name: 'Carly',
                yearOfBirth: 1942,
                yearOfDeath: 1970,
            }, {
                name: 'Ray',
                yearOfBirth: 1962,
                yearOfDeath: 2011
            }, {
                name: 'Jane',
                yearOfBirth: 1912,
                yearOfDeath: 1941
            }, ]

            return people.reduce((oldest, currentPerson) => {
                const oldestAge = getAge(oldest.yearOfBirth, oldest.yearOfDeath)
                const currentAge = getAge(currentPerson.yearOfBirth, currentPerson.yearOfDeath)
                return oldestAge < currentAge ? currentPerson : oldest;
            })
        }

        const getAge = function(birth, death) {
            if (!death) {
                death = new Date().getFullYear();
            }
            return death - birth;
        }


        console.log(findTheOldest());```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reduce is a generic operation that basically says "Iterate over all elements, and return a value". It is an extremely generic function that can be used for far more than just summing. The function you pass it basically says "Assume the current state is `X`. If you look at item `Y`, how does the state change?". For the function above, that basically translates to "Assume the oldest person is `oldest`. Compare them to `currentPerson`. Return the oldest person between `oldest` and `currentPerson`". Reduce applies that basic logic to each element in `people`. After you have looked at all people, you know that `oldest` will be the oldest person.

All that matters is you iterate over some elements, and use those elements to compute an intermediate result. By the end of iterating over all elements, that intermediate result will be your final result.

Here are just a few simple examples of other things you can use reduce to do:

You can implement a filter (i.e., return an new array where each element matches some criteria defined in a function)

```
const filter = (array, fn) => {
  return array.reduce((filtered, item) => {
    if (fn(item)) filtered.push(item)
    return filtered
  }, [])
}
filter([1,2,3], (item) => item >= 2)
```

You can use it to re-implement `map` in a similar way (i.e., return a new array where each element is transformed by some function)

```
const map = (array, fn) => {
  return array.reduce((filtered, item) => {
    filtered.push(fn(item))
    return filtered
  }, [])
}
map([1,2,3], (item) => item*2)
```

You can use it to return a range (i.e., return the minimum and maximum values from some array):

```
const range = (array) => {
  return array.reduce(([min, max], item) => {
    if (max < item) max = item
    if (min > item) min = item
    return [min, max]
  }, [Infinity, -Infinity])
}
range([1,2,3])
```

Comment: This is the best explanation I have read by far. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the `accumulator` to sum multiple numbers it basically calculates the age of each person as it loops over each object and if that person is older than the previous person it returns that person's object as the next value of the `accumulator`, so ultimately the final returned value will be the oldest person. It might help to add some console.logs like:

```js
return people.reduce((oldest, currentPerson) => {
    const oldestAge = getAge(oldest.yearOfBirth, oldest.yearOfDeath)
    const currentAge = getAge(currentPerson.yearOfBirth, currentPerson.yearOfDeath)
    console.log('oldest: ', oldest.name, oldestAge)
    console.log('currentPerson: ', currentPerson.name, currentAge)
    return oldestAge < currentAge ? currentPerson : oldest;
})
```

Answer (score 1):

The arguments to the callback of `reduce` are the accumulator and the current element. Since you did not specify an initial value, the accumulator starts as the first element, and you reduce starting from the second. On each iteration, the current person's age is compared to the current oldest person's age. The oldest of the two is then returned, which becomes the accumulator for the next iteration (or the end result, if that was the last element).

See also: [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)